# Draw rectangle where finger is?

Tags: java, android, xml, algorithm, canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle on the Android canvas at the very right side of the screen along my finger:

[image] (LOOK CLOSELY, see that red dot? I want that red dot to appear along the side of the screen at the X axis of where I tapped)

I've divided the screen into 100x100 grid:

```
gridSizePx_w = width/100;
gridSizePx_h = height/100;
```

And I draw the red square here:

```
 public void drawInitialBullet(float x) {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();

        if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
             Canvas screenCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();


            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);

            screenCanvas.drawRect(width-gridSizePx_w, ((int) x)-gridSizePx_w, width, ((int) x) + gridSizePx_h, paint );
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(screenCanvas);
        }
    }
```

After getting a touch event here:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                 drawInitialBullet(motionEvent.getX());

            Toast.makeText(myContext, "YEAH", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

        return true;
    }
```

However, for some reason, the square is **never** appearing along side the correct X axis—it always appears some random place along the side of the screen unrelated to where I tap.

Please let me know if you notice any issues in my code.

Comment: What's width?  The code to define it isn't shown here.  Without that its hard to tell what you're actually drawing at

Comment: Also, your top parameter-  ((int) x)-gridSizePx_w  what's x?  And shouldn't that be _h, not _w?

Comment: @GabeSechan x is generated from my on touch event, that's when I call the method like so: `drawInitialBullet(motionEvent.getX());`

Comment: @GabeSechan I get the width of the screen using `width = point.x;
        height = point.y;` where I get point from another class using `Display screen = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point p = new Point();

        screen.getSize(p);`

Comment: Then your top calculation is totally wrong. You're changing the top of your rectangle breed on the x position. You want to change it based on the y. That would display it on the right of the screen across from your finger, which is what I think you're trying to do

Comment: Same problem with bottom- should be y.